# Ways to get SMD resistors from a strip

Tags: soldering, surface-mount

I'm doing some SMD hand soldering occasionally and am looking for a better way of getting SMD resistors from a strip, so their orientation is upside up and their reading is e.g. from left to right.
I normally just peel off the cover foil, but then the "pile" looks like the picture below.
I thought of removing the foil and use adhesive tape to get them out. Then, the resistors are aligned equally, but upside down, so, not practical.

[image]

So, what are ways to get SMD resistors from a strip, such they are upside up and aligned equally?

BTW, to get a clearer picture I showed 1206 resistors, but I mainly use 0603 (Imperial code).

Comment: Have you tried vacuum tweezers? Tape the strip on a desk and remove the plastic, the vacuum tweezer will pull the resistor out. (Basically same process as pick & place machine)

Comment: It's a pity they don't print on both sides.

Comment: @WesleyLee No, I haven't. I didn't know they exist. Thanks.

Comment: @WesleyLee If you tape them to the bench you can just pick them out with regular tweezers. Don't need vacuum tweezers.

Comment: @DKNguyen - for me picking and placing is a lot faster with the vacuum tool, not only for resistors, but also capacitors, diodes, even ICs. Granted there is more overhead for the setup, so it is generally only worth it if you are assembling a lot of parts at a time. (The vacuum tweezer also helps to rotate the part by twisting the fingers when you place them)

Comment: (and for some tighter tapes/components my tweezers don't fit between the paper/plastic and component)

Comment: @DKNguyen Wesley Lee mentioned, even with sharp pointed tweezers, I tried and failed picking 0603 resistors from the strip 90% of the time. But for other components, I like the idea.

Comment: Weird. I do 0603 all the time.

Comment: @DKNguyen As in easily? In my case, there hardly is any room between the paper and the component, not even for sharp pointed tweezers. Are you maybe pressing the paper outwards, making room while picking the component? Could you by chance make a picture doing it?

Comment: @Huisman I went back and paid more attention to how I do it. It turns out I grab it by the ends where there is space and I use my 0.17mm tip tweezers. Those ones aren't small enough to get at it from the side. I wonder if the 0.07mm tweezers can get at it from the side but I don't own a pair.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should try vacuum tweezers. They are a bit varied, there are some super cheap ones and others more sophisticated:

Cheapest option, which I dont recommend. When you press or release the vacuum pump the tweezer moves, which makes placing parts precisely a bit harder.

[image]

There are some automated versions, some come with a pedal for instance where you can enable or disable the vacuum. (the image is illustrative, I don't know which features it has)

[image]

Some of them have a metal arm which you can use to help place the parts even more precisely. This is a "cheap" one from Tindie, but there are some that are a lot more rigid and expensive (didn't find a picture when writing the answer).

[image]

Or **build your own** (out of the first one).

I have 2 that are made with aquarium pumps, [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcxNrJXnznc) guys posted a guide on how to build one. Mike (Mikes Electric Stuff) has a nice [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdGSFc7VjBE&t=4m34s) about the topic as well.

Some time ago I posted a [video](https://youtu.be/JhlJLR0Djkg) of some PCB population some boards using mine. In my case I sealed an aquarium pump with hot glue leaving only one exit for the air, and I block that exit with my hand. When the exit is blocked the part is released (tackyness from the paste helps release the part from the resitual vacuum).

[image]

Comment: Upvoted because, oh, wow, now I want one!

Comment: @JulieinAustin - build your own! :P

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to remove the cover foil. Then use some scotch tape to tape where the cover foil was and making sure you touch the resistors as well. When you now peel the scotch tape off, you have all resistors nicely on the scotchtape. Sadly all inverted. 
But you can grab them with normal tweezers now